# How do I remove the namespace values from my nested XML child elements?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, serialization

I have a small RESTful web service powered by Jackson, Jersey, EclipseLink and Tomcat.  For the most part, the XML is working as expected except when it comes to my nested child elements.  They are written with namespace attributes when the rest of the XML document isn't.  Here's a sample of the response XML:

```
<userView>
    <userIdSID>5</userIdSID>
    <userAuthLevel>5</userAuthLevel>
    <userRoles>
        <roleSID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:decimal">1</roleSID>
        <roleSID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:decimal">3</roleSID>
        <roleSID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:decimal">2</roleSID>
        <roleSID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:decimal">8</roleSID>
        <roleSID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:decimal">5</roleSID>
        <roleSID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:decimal">4</roleSID>
        <roleSID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:decimal">9</roleSID>
        <roleSID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:decimal">1000001</roleSID>
    </userRoles>
</userView>
```

This is what my UserRoleList.java looks like:

```
package com.company.project;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserRoleList implements Serializable {

    private int userRoleSID;

    public int getUserRoleSid() {
        return userRoleSID;
    }

    public void setUserRoleSid(int userRoleSid) {
        this.userRoleSID = userRoleSid;
    }
}
```

This is what my UserView.java looks like:

```
package com.company.project;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class UserView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID_SID")
    private String userIdSID;
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private String userAuthLevel;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "userRoles")
    @XmlElement(name = "roleSID")
    private List<UserRoleList> userRoleList = new ArrayList<UserRoleList>();

    public UserView() {
    }

    public UserView(String userIdSID) {
        this.userIdSID = userIdSID;
    }

    public String getUserIdSID() {
        return userIdSID;
    }

    public void setUserIdSID(String userIdSID) {
        this.userIdSID = userIdSID;
    }

    public List<UserRoleList> getUserRoleList() {
        return userRoleList;
    }

    public void setUserRoleList(List<UserRoleList> userRoleList) {
        this.userRoleList = userRoleList;
    }

    public String getUserAuthLevel() {
        return userAuthLevel;
    }

    public void setUserAuthLevel(String userAuthLevel) {
        this.userAuthLevel = userAuthLevel;
    }
}
```

This is how I populate that nest element, it takes 2 inbound parameters and performs a query via an Entity Manager:

```
 List<UserRoleList> userRoleList = em.createNamedQuery("findRoleListByLoginName")
                    .setParameter(1, id)
                    .setParameter(2, client)
                    .getResultList();
```

Any thoughts as to where I might be missing something?  I have tried using a pkg-info to no avail.  Mind you, this output constructs an XML that doesn't have a schema generated from it.  Not sure if that helps or hinders but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**: As requested, here's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>moxyWS</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Multiple packages, separated by semicolon(;), can be specified in param-value</description>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.project.moxyws</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <persistence-unit-ref>
        <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence-factory</persistence-unit-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>moxyWS_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>
</web-app>
```

**UPDATE 2**: As requested, here's my REST Facade:

```
package com.project.moxyws.service;

import com.project.moxyws.UserView;
import com.project.moxyws.controller.UserViewJPAController;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;

@Path("request")
public class UserViewRESTFacade {

    private EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        return (EntityManagerFactory) Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("moxyWS_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
    }

    private UserViewJPAController getJpaController() {
        try {
            return new UserViewJPAController(getEntityManagerFactory());
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public UserViewRESTFacade() {
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{client}/{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public UserView findUserByClientAndID(@PathParam("client") String client, @PathParam("id") String id) {
        try {
            return getJpaController().findUserId(id, client);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(204);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just putting your code into a JAXBContext and then creating a marshaller will output `<roleSID><userRoleSID>#</userRoleSID></roleSID>` for each roleSID.  I imagine it's a setting in your Jersey marshalling configuration, package info, or you arn't using those files in your codebase?

Comment: Added XmlValue attribute and it spits out the correct output.  Still don't see the namespacing that you are getting.

Comment: Oh, I see.  If I understand correctly, you're thinking I should create a new @Provider JAXBContext so Jersey can use this custom one as opposed as the default one?

Comment: No, I'm saying their default one shouldn't be adding these namespaces unless you have a setting/configuration somewhere

Comment: Hmm... let me review the whole code again.  I'm pretty sure I didn't include anything that would do any such thing.

Comment: Searched and found nothing out of the ordinary; not sure where i can go from here.

Comment: post your web.xml along with your jersey endpoint code if you want help. I'm not confident the code you posted already is what is being used in your system, because it would need @xmlvalue for it to not have a sub-element.

Comment: Posted as requested.  Help is much appreciated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30030/discussion-between-dmoses-and-mastashake57)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't pin down the one answer but they all, collectively, gave me the idea to begin checking my SQL onstructs.  As it turns out, my `UserRoleList` class is taking in the data type of `int`.  On the other side of the fence, my `ResultList` was a list of `BigDecimal` data types.

To remove any and all ambiguity, I modified my SQL statement to return the value as `VARCHAR` which would be taken in as a `String` data type object.  I updated my `UserRoleList` class to represent `String` objects and it all works now.

I'll revisit my code to reflect the proper binding of data types but, for now, this gets me over the hump so I can finish prototyping my solution.  Many thanks to all, especially to **DMoses**, for a quick and productive brainstorming session.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your UserRoleList class, which is a class with a single field, which you really want to map to a simple type.  you may want to try annotating the `userRoleSID` member with the `@XmlValue` annotation.

Comment: I tried this suggestion and it seems that Jersey/Jackson didn't like it:  `Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.`

Comment: Mind you, I removed any references I saw relevant to `@XmlElement` and still got that error.

Answer (score 1):

When mapping JPA entities with JAXB I recommend using the default access (or XmlAccessType.PROPERTY) and annotate the get methods.  JPA impls have tricks to handle things such lazy loading that sometimes causes problems when field access is used.